# The WineHQ PPA does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, updates

```
$ sudo apt-get update

Ign:1 http://mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint/packages ulyana InRelease          
Ign:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubu... focal InRelease                                    
Err:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubu... focal Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.158.217 443]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]       
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,972 B]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubu... focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file). This looks like a Mint question, not an Ubuntu question, so it may or may not apply. We don't keep track of whatever changes or secret sauce Mint adds.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Answer (score 2):

You need to contact WineHQ for this.

As of right now, Wine upstream does *not* have a Focal version published in their repositories.  Only they can fix it.